# python list index issue

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a fairly basic python issue, here's the code:

```
def LCM(nums): 
    i = max(nums)
    var = 0
    x = 0
    while i>0:
        for x in nums:
            var = var+int(nums[x])%i
        if (var == 0):
            return i
        i=i-1
```

`nums` is a list, I think `x` is the index for that list, and the `for` statement should iterate through each value in the list as `nums[x]`. It seems like `x` should start at the first element of `nums`, and iterate through each value till nums runs out of values.

Instead, I get `list index out of range`, I don't understand how this is possible.
Is my `for` syntax screwed up? I can't make this make sense.

Comment: submitting the code destroyed the indents for some reason, I can resubmit if its too confusing

Comment: think I fixed it.  (You don't need to use [code], simply select the text and hit the {} button above the entry box, or hit control-K).  Could you check that the indenting of each line is correct now?

Answer (score 4):

`x` is not an index. `x` is an element in the `list`.

Also, you don't need parentheses around an `if`-condition.

### Simple demonstration:

```
>>> nums = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
>>> for x in nums:
...     if x % 3 == 0:
...         print x, 'is divisible by three'
...     else:
...         print x
... 
11
12 is divisible by three
13
14
15 is divisible by three
16
```

Answer (score 2):

As others said, `x` is an element of `nums`. For sake of completeness, if you want to iterate a list and have access to the index, have a look at [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for i, x in enumerate(nums):
    print i, x #nums[i] == x
```

Comment: You may want to actually call `enumerate()` in your example ;)

Comment: @Johnsyweb what do you mean? :)

Answer (score 0):

`x` already is an element of `nums`. Replace `nums[x]` by `x`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to travel the elements using it's index, you can use

```
for x in range (len(nums)):
```

instead of

```
for x in nums:
```

because in your code it is travelling via the index of the i'th value from the list.
Like suppose the very first value of the list is 34 and list is of size 5, so according to your code you are trying to travel 34'th index value from the list which is why you getting.

> list index out of range